# Rails credentials:edit & uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In rails 5.2, I'm running into an error when attempting to modify Rails credentials.

Running either one of these commands.

```
EDITOR="vim --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

throws an error **uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)**, details below...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    14: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    13: from /Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    12: from /Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    11: from /Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    10: from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
     8: from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
     7: from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
     6: from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
     5: from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     4: from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/credentials/credentials_command.rb:20:in `edit'
     3: from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:17:in `require_application_and_environment!'
     2: from /Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
     1: from /Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
/Users/mm/Documents/development/byte/api/config/application.rb:18:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
```

Bundler is installed

```
bundler -v

Bundler version 1.16.2
```

And I did delete and recreate the Gemfile.lock file. Thoughts? Many thanks.

Comment: have you tried without `bin/`?

Comment: try bundler exec rails credentials:edit

Comment: @sethi, that did it. Prepending the command with 'bundler' worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the lines where you use the credentials before you edit them, it worked for me.